# PHP RegEx string contains more than two numbers next to each other enclosed with slashes

Tags: php, regex

My RegEx is poor, and I have been struggling with this. I have some URL's that contain a pattern like this:

```
/1234/
/5527191/
/15974/
```

And so on. It's always a bunch of letters, then a slash, numbers ( no more than 10 numbers) and then another slash.

So I'm after some RegEx that will search, ignore letters and find a group of numbers bewteen two slashes.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) (or [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) if you only want the first match) with the following regular expression:

```
preg_match_all("#/\d{1,10}/#", $s, $matches);
```

**Explanation**

- `#` is the [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for the regular expression.
- `/` matches a literal slash.
- `\d` matches any digit.
- `{1,10}` matches the previous token between 1 and 10 times.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/iHY3y)

If you want to also capture the number without the slashes you could use a capturing group:

```
preg_match_all("#/(\d{1,10})/#", $s, $matches);
```

Comment: OP might need a grouping in there to extract the string

Comment: Hey Mark, I actually need to do the same thing in JavaScript using .search(). Is the RegEx the same?